# Android: Best way to pass data between activities when using ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have an activity called `SearchActivity` that has a `ListView` with a subset of data (title and distance) from a JSON download. I want to show all the JSON data and complete record in another activity called `ResultsActivity`. I know how to get data from the `ListView` itself and pass it to the other activity, but I am not sure how to get at all the data to pass to the second activity.

For example, I would like for the onClickListener to do a lookup into the ArrayList for the currently selected item so that I can do something like this:

in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
in.putExtra(TAG_STREET, street);
ect.

The problem being that the only thing displayed in the ListView is the name and distance. How can I get at the ArrayList entry using the current Listview selection so I can display the street for example?

Any help appreciated.

```
SearchActivity.java
package com.chance.squat;

import com.chance.squat.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SearchActivity extends ListActivity {

    // url to make request
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.115:3000/bathrooms/nearby.json/?lat=45.580639&lon=-122.677682";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_BATHROOMS = "bathrooms";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID";
    private static final String TAG_ACCESS = "access";
    private static final String TAG_CITY = "city";
    private static final String TAG_COMMENT = "comment";
    private static final String TAG_DIRECTIONS = "directions";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_STREET = "street";
    private static final String TAG_BATHROOMTYPE = "bathroomtype";
    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE = "distance";
    private static final String TAG_AVAIL = "avail";
    private static final String TAG_COUNTRY = "country";
    private static final String TAG_STATE = "state";
    private static final String TAG_POSTAL = "postal";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray bathrooms = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> bathroomList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            bathrooms = json.getJSONArray(TAG_BATHROOMS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = 0; i < bathrooms.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = bathrooms.getJSONObject(i);


                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String access = c.getString(TAG_ACCESS);
                String city = c.getString(TAG_CITY);
                String comment = c.getString(TAG_COMMENT);
                String directions = c.getString(TAG_DIRECTIONS);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String street = c.getString(TAG_STREET);
                String bathroomtype = c.getString(TAG_BATHROOMTYPE);                
                String distance = c.getString(TAG_DISTANCE);
                String distanceTrimmed = distance.substring(0,4) + " " + "miles away";
                String avail = c.getString(TAG_AVAIL);
                String country = c.getString(TAG_COUNTRY);
                String state = c.getString(TAG_STATE);
                String postal = c.getString(TAG_POSTAL);

                System.out.println(name);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_ACCESS, access);
                map.put(TAG_CITY, city);
                map.put(TAG_COMMENT, comment);
                map.put(TAG_DIRECTIONS, directions);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_STREET, street);
                map.put(TAG_BATHROOMTYPE, bathroomtype);
                map.put(TAG_DISTANCE, distanceTrimmed);
                map.put(TAG_AVAIL, avail);
                map.put(TAG_COUNTRY, country);
                map.put(TAG_STATE, state);
                map.put(TAG_POSTAL, postal);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                bathroomList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, bathroomList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_DISTANCE}, new int[] {
                         R.id.name, R.id.distance });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                //String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                //String distance = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.distance)).getText().toString();


                // Starting new intent
                //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeachActivity.class);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                //in.putExtra(TAG_DISTANCE, distance);
                //startActivity(in);

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: SO you want to send a specific record to the next activity or the complete ArrayList? You can send both if you want to

Comment: I just want to send a specific record namely the one referenced by the curently selected ListView selection but I don't know how to get a reference to the ArrayList using the ListView?

Answer (score 0):

[Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29)
`getItem(position)`

Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set.

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you can call [getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) on the adapter .

alternatively , you can create your own adapter which extends from BaseAdapter . there you will have full control of the data to use and return (using [getItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29)) .

also , whenever possible , google suggests to use fragments instead of activities .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the specific object and value from the ListView using `onItemClickListener()` method of ListView adapter, which got d click. The next step would be to search in the ArrayList (assuming you saved the complete data in an ArrayList), using a `for loop`.

For example, you can just get the title string from the ListView and search in the ArrayList. You need to have access to the ArrayList in ListActivity for that. If it's not accessible, try using bundles or if the data is frequently used across more than 2 activities, you can also use static class to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

try as to get selected ListItem ArrayList :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

 @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
               int position, long id) {
   // getting values from selected ListItem
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrhashmap=
             (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

   // Starting new intent
   Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SeachActivity.class);
   in.putExtra("arralsthasmap", arrhashmap);
   startActivity(in);
```

}
});

and in other Activity retrieve ArrayList as :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrhashmap 
                      =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) 
          getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arralsthasmap");
```

Comment: Would this pass the entire array or just the corresponding selected item?

Comment: @JohnnyRottenweed : this will pass entire Hashmap at selected Position in ListView

Comment: 01-19 15:37:17.482: E/AndroidRuntime(424): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap on the onItemClick code.